# Spring Webflow Jsf integration war not working in Glassfishv3 server

Tags: java, spring, jsf, glassfish, spring-webflow

Spring-Webflow JSF intgration war example(http://www.springsource.org/webflow-samples/spring-booking-faces.war) file from spring site is not working in GlassfishV3 server. It works in Tomcat6.0.
In Glassfish, It throws following exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
 at javax.faces.context.FacesContext.getAttributes(FacesContext.java:141)
 at com.sun.faces.util.RequestStateManager.get(RequestStateManager.java:194)
 at com.sun.faces.util.Util.getFacesMapping(Util.java:564)
 at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.derivePhysicalViewId(MultiViewHandler.java:483)
 at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.restoreView(MultiViewHandler.java:142)
 at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowViewHandler.restoreView(FlowViewHandler.java:77)
 at org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfViewFactory.getView(JsfViewFactory.java:97)
 at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:198)
 at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:551)
 at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:263)
 ... 40 more
```

Comment: I saw very similar problem when I used JSF 20 with webflow. Switching to JSF 1.2 helped. Check the versions of JSF that are used in Tomcat and in Glassfish.

Answer (score 1):

I received a similar error that you are facing sometime back . Try replacing your JSF jars with the following jars.I guess it is using Primefaces too . Use following combination of jars

```
[INFO] +- com.sun.faces:jsf-api:jar:2.0.3-b05:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.faces:jsf-impl:jar:2.0.3-b05:runtime
[INFO] +- org.primefaces:primefaces:jar:2.2.RC2:compile
```

Please let me know if you still face any problem